# Reference to missing date in Tableau

Tags: date, tableau-api

I am trying to retrieve closing stock price of the 1st trading day for the month. I use the following formula and successful gives me the first Monday of the month, but I want to have Tuesday when Monday is a holiday(thus missing in the dataset).

```
IF DATENAME('weekday', DATETRUNC('month',[Date])) ="Saturday" THEN DATETRUNC('month',[Date])+2
ELSEIF DATENAME('weekday', DATETRUNC('month',[Date])) ="Sunday" THEN DATETRUNC('month',[Date])+1
ELSE DATETRUNC('month',[Date])
END
```

How do I reference it in the calculated field? I tried NULL but it doesn't work.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may maintain the list of holidays by date and a flag in a csv file. Then do a full outer join of this file with your data. This will bring in the missing dates and you can check if it is a holiday.